# Form is not posted in IE in mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

My form is submitted correctly in all browser all functions working right. But In IE the form is not posted.

I have searched and found the issue of cache. But nothing works. This is my code.

```
$('#newUserForm').submit(function () {

    debugger;

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    var formData = form.serialize();

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $.post(url, formData, function (result) {
        if (result.redirect) {
            window.location.href = result.redirect;         
            return;
        } else {
            UserRoles.cleanData();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What version(s) of IE? Errors in the dev tools console?

Comment: Nothing error is displayed. It works in all browser. But not working in IE . I try in IE 8 and IE 10

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `debugger;` line from your js. I believe your form works in ie, but only while the developer console is open. The ie stops all script execution after a `console.log()` for example, while the dev console is closed.

As a workaround, you could ask the window object if a console is opened:

```
if (window.console) {
  debugger;
}
```

Comment: I don't know about earlier versions, but IE11 is just ignoring the statement if the Dev Tools aren't open, and running the rest of the code. That's a bit different to `console.log` which results in an actual JavaScript error because there is no console object to access the `log` function.